# Why does ESlint disallow file extensions in imports, given that browsers refuse to load such imports?

Tags: javascript, import, module, eslint

I have the following line in my browser-facing Javascript code:

```
import {
    appendWhileKeepingBottomScroll,
    UserNickDisplay, showThrobber, hideThrobber
} from './utils.js'
```

[ESlint doesn't like this line.](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/extensions.md)

> Unexpected use of file extension "js" for "./utils.js"

Problem is, when I remove the `.js` extension from this statement, ESlint starts liking my Javascript code BUT Firefox stops liking it and refuses to load `utils.js` and throws an exception. It complains that `https://localhost:44336/js/utils` has an incorrect MIME type. So it doesn't even TRY to load `utils.js`!!

Yes I know I can switch off this validation in ESlint. But I can't shake off the fealing I must be missing something obvious. ESLint simply CAN'T, by default, suggest changes that break the code? Can it?

Why does ESLint suggest by default omitting file extensions from imports?

Comment: My guess is that they think it much more likely to be used in the context of a build process (in which case the module system used could resolve the extension automatically) than in the context of a plain `.js` which is directly on a site. Native ES6 imports are not all that widely supported yet (eg, FF May 2018+) unfortunately

Comment: Do you have a `type="text/javascript"` attribute on your script tag?

Comment: @MinusFour He's using `import`, so it's definitely `type="module"`

Comment: You are right. I wouldn't pay much attention to this rule anyway. The rule doesn't even seem to be part of eslint core. It might need to add environmental configuration.